# How to clear ItemListView.SelectedItems when my dialog box is closed in C#?

Tags: c#, dialog, listviewitem

I have been using ListViewItem for my list dialog box. My current problem right now is that when I close the dialog box, my SelectedItem does not return null or empty.

[image: Here is the sample dialog box I created]

With the reference image, the current selected items would be Item1 and Item5. When I closed the dialog box and doesn't select anything, it was supposed to return an error when I clicked on "Add" button. But what happens is, it proceeds and gave me the values of the selected item on my previous transaction.

I have been setting this ListViewItem to null on different parts of my code, some on button click event handlers but it is still not working. I am thinking of adding an event handler for the close button but I don't know the workaround for dialog boxes.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the [`ListView.SelectedIndices.Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexcollection.clear?view=netframework-4.8) method on the `ListView` that contains the `ListViewItem`:

```
myListView.SelectedIndices.Clear();
```

Note that you will need to replace `myListView` within the example above to the name of your `ListView` control that contains the `ListViewItem`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this one and no SelectedIndices property is available. There is SelectedIndex, though this doesn't have Clear() property. I believe SelectedIndices is not supported for C#, but rather in C++. I am quite not sure with this.